# Sorting data into categories based on length of a number and parts of the number

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, dplyr

I have the following data frame.

| User | Ident |
| --- | --- |
| User 1 | 45668 |
| User 2 | 68445 |
| User 3 | 75006 |
| User 4 | 8000 |

```
User<- c("User1","User2","User3","User4")
Ident <- c(45668,68445,75006,8000)
df<-data.frame("User"=User,"Ident"=Ident)
```

I want now a thrid column, created with the following conditions:

- If the number has four digits => Category "Cat_Unknown"
- If the number has five digits, put them into a category based on the first two digits. e.g.
- 45*** == Cat A
- 68*** == Cat A
- 75*** == Cat B

Added information, based on a comment: I changed => to ==. It is not a range. Every two digit number can have an individual "Ident_Cat".

| User | Ident | Ident_Cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 45668 | Cat A |
| User 2 | 68445 | Cat A |
| User 3 | 75006 | Cat B |
| User 4 | 8000 | Cat_Unknown |

I can use:

```
c <- df %>% 
  +     filter(substr(df2$Ident, 1,2) == 45)
c$Ident_Cat<-"CatA"
```

and `rbind`

But this seems like a nasty workaround.

Any ideas.
Thanks

Comment: Create a new column using mutate that uses floor(ident/1000), which will give 45, 65, 75, 8 as values. Then use forcats to apply categories? Not clear if 10-74 are cat A, >74 cat B, <10 unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like this:

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

User<- c("User1","User2","User3","User4")
Ident <- c(45668,68445,75006,8000)
df<-data.frame("User"=User,"Ident"=Ident)

df %>%
mutate(cat = as_factor(floor(Ident/1000)))%>%
mutate(cat =fct_collapse( cat,
Unknown ="8",
A = c("45","68"),
B = "75"))
```

Or more scalable?

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

User<- c("User1","User2","User3","User4")
Ident <- c(45668,68445,75006,8000)
df<-data.frame("User"=User,"Ident"=Ident)

U <- as.character(c(0:9))
A <- as.character(c(10:69))
B <-as.character(c(70:99))

df %>%
mutate(cat = as_factor(floor(Ident/1000)))%>%
mutate(cat =fct_collapse( cat,
Unknown = U,
A = A,
B = B))
```

Gives warning but it's not an error